# error when using parse functions outside of the app delegate

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

Using Xcode 6 beta 6 to set up my app with parse.com. I followed the instructions listed [here](http://blog.parse.com/2014/06/06/building-apps-with-parse-and-swift/) and got the framework imported into my app and added the bridged header etc. I then added my app keys into my app delegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        Parse.setApplicationId("app key here", clientKey: "client key here")
        var testObject = PFObject(className: "test")
        testObject["foo"] = "bar"
        testObject.saveInBackground()

        return true
    }
```

and that worked fine. I verified the test object was created in the data browser and thought I was set. then I started working on implementing logon into my app. in my first view controller I create a current user variable and my app crashes with the following error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'You have to call setApplicationId:clientKey: on Parse to configure Parse.'

Well I did set it, and it works in my app delegate, but for some reason, any parse code outside the app delegate causes this crash. I even pasted the test code again in my view controller and it doesnt even autocomplete anything after the first line of parse related code

```
class HomeViewController: UITableViewController {

    var testObject = PFObject(className: "test")
    //this line after the first has a "expected expression error" and no parse methods get autocompleted
    testObject["foo"] = "bar"
    testObject.saveInBackground()
```

has anyone else had this problem? is it a problem with xcode 6?

Comment: Did you `#include <Parse/Parse.h>` in your view controller?

Comment: I added the import in the bridged header file. I thought that since it was in the bridged header I wouldnt need to import it anywhere else.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw that it is swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While working on another app I realized what I had done when I had this problem. I was trying to initialize a property to store the current user, but I was doing it outside of view did load so it must have been getting called before the app delegate call to configure parse even ran. After initializing it inside of viewDidLoad instead of when declaring the property it worked fine.